# Running a for loop only after an if condition has been met

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I'm currently trying to make a very simply testing function that first checks to see if the users input is a multiple of 3, then tests each individual character to see if they are valid characters. Here's my code below:

```
def is_dna(string):

    string.upper() 
    if(len(string) % 3 == 0):
        print("LENGTH CORRECT")
        for n in string:
            if(n == "A" or n == "T" or n == "C" or n == "G"):
                print("Valid")
            else:
                print("Invalid character")
                break
        return True
    else:
        print("Too many/little characters")
        return False
```

When run, the bottom section will run fine, and if a correct amount of characters is used this will also successfully print the debug "LENGTH CORRECT" string. The issue is that the for loop will not initialize, and I haven't the foggiest why. Testing just the loop shows it to work fine; what is wrong with this function?

Comment: `string.upper() ` won't change the string. A *new string* with the characters converted is returned.

Comment: The loop initialises just fine, but you still return `True` anyway, regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Thank you Martijn, you identified the issue. The string.upper was the key fault here. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, you can validate the letters more efficiently using set operations, eg `{'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'}.issuperset(string.upper())`.

Comment: What do you meant with "not initialize", not even "Invalid character" gets printed? If you want to check the validity of a string content, I suggest using regular expressions, something like: `re.match("[ATCG]{3}", string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple fix
you just need to have the string.upper() move into a variable then act upon the variable

code that is fixed

```
def is_dna(stri):
    string = stri.upper() 
    if(len(string) % 3 == 0):
        print("LENGTH CORRECT")
        for n in string:
            if(n == "A" or n == "T" or n == "C" or n == "G"):
                print("Valid")
            else:
                print("Invalid character")
                break
        return True
    else:
        print("Too many/little characters")
    return False
is_dna("ATCGCTATC") #this works and tests it perfectly
```

Comment: Adding onto this, if anyone in future has this issue place a "return False" in the loop break section otherwise you will return True regardless. Thanks for the answer, this is the error!

Comment: Also, this code returns `True` even if `"Invalid character"` is printed.

Comment: @FragilePixel Why do you want the `is_dna` test to return `True` if it has the correct length even when the string contains invalid characters? That seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = string.upper()
```

the function upper() just return the uppercase of the character,the string self is not change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the cycle, just use regular expressions:

```
import re

def is_dna(string)
    return re.match("([CAGT]{3})+", string.upper()) is not None
```

Comment: Use `is not None` instead of `!= None`.